# Duration Format Change

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Is is possible to change a duration format from for example '47 Years 3 Months' to just '16,822', representing the amount of days in said duration?

Comment: Welcome! How to take into account the count of days February 29 in these 47 years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duration phrases like `47 Years 3 Months` are ambiguous, because a year can be 365 days or 366 days, or in the past during calendar system changes may have been something else completely. Further, months vary between 28 and 31 days in length. So the number of days depends on the start date for the duration.

Nevertheless, you can get a pretty decent estimate of the number of days with something like this:

`=365.2425 * regexextract(A1, "(?i)(\d+) year") + 365.2425 / 12 * regexextract(A1, "(?i)(\d+) month")`

Comment: ...which will return 17257.70813, not "16.822" - and this is the correct result